# ngTagsInput autocomplete on the text AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have to create a text field TagsInput but it must load the data into the text ngTagsInput

For example, when the letter "Ab" is field, the autocomplete should display all the employee email address that starts with "Ab".

The problem I have is that I can not have a source that is static so I have to load the data as a measure of the text entered in the ngTagsInput.

Have you any idea?

I don't know that i have to get on loadTags's parameter

THIS IS MY ngTagsInput

```
                <tags-input ng-model="email.TO">
                <auto-complete source="loadTags(newTag.text)"></auto-complete>
            </tags-input>
```

MY loadTags PROCEDURE

```
    $scope.loadTags = function (val) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
   // var test = $scope.newTag.text;
    $http.get("../api/Employee/getAutocomplet", {
        params: { sSearch: val }
    }).then(function (response) {
        var addresses = [];
        angular.forEach(response.data, function (item) {
            addresses.push(item.Email);
        });
        deferred.resolve(addresses);
    });

    return deferred.promise;   
}
```

Comment: Can you maybe explain to me what exactly you mean with `I don't know that i have to get on loadTags's parameter`? Don't you know how to access the tag that you're trying to autocomplete?