# Error: promise is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, ng-tags-input

I am using angularjs to create a tag list input.
When I type more than 3 characters in tag list control the following error is shown in browser console.

AngularJS v1.2.23
ngTagsInput v2.1.0

```
Error: promise is undefined
SuggestionList/self.load/debouncedLoadId
```

HTML:

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags" display-property="Tag_Title" placeholder="Add Tag">
<auto-complete source="loadItems($query)"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

app.js:

```
$scope.loadTags = function(query) {
    return $http.get('getTags?query=' + query).then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug fixed. In my HTML code the function name was "loadItems" but in app.js the function was named "loadTags". 
The complete solution is:

**HTML**

```
<tags-input ng-model="myTags" display-property="Tag_Title" placeholder="Add Tag">
    <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

**app.js**

```
$scope.myTags = [];

$scope.loadTags = function(query) {
    return $http.get('getTags?query=' + query)
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
    });
}
```

**php**
For server-side I have used Laravel framework

```
public function getTags() 
{
    $query = Input::get('query');

    return Tag::where('Tag_Title', 'LIKE', $query.'%')->get();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why those downvotes? the error is simple: `loadTags()` must return a promise, but you're returning the result data of the `$http` call instead.

so your `loadTags()` function should be:

```
$scope.loadTags = function(query) {
    return $http.get('getTags?query=' + query);
}
```

you have to make sure the backend delivers a data structure like this:

```
[
    {text:'foo'},
    {text:'foo2'},
    {text:'foo3'}
]
```

in case your backend delivers something else, you have to transform the result first; see the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22955795/176140) for how that's done. just come back to me if you need further help on this.